# SlideTransition in flutter takes space before it slides in

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I implemented SlideTransition for a widget in flutter, and it slides in as expected. The issue is that before the animation is called, the space where the slider is going to be displayed later is empty.

How can I make the parent to give this space to other widgets in the layout until the moment that a slider comes into view?

I was thinking about giving a slider the initial height of zero, but then the widgets inside the slider would act funny as the height changes in sync with sliding. I wonder if there is a simpler way.

The parent is:

```
new Scaffold(
    appBar: _appBar,
    body: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Expanded(
          child: _body;
          }),
        ),
        new SlideTransition(
          position: _sliderPosition, // 
          child: _slider,
        ),
      ],
    );
```

And the position is defined as:

```
_sliderPosition = new MaterialPointArcTween(
  begin: const Offset(0.0, 1.0),
  end: Offset.zero,
).animate(_animationController);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by replacing `_slider` with `_buildSlider()` which returns `null` until a slider is needed.

This is also better for performance as there is no need to render a slider if it's hidden.

Comment: as for the flutter performance claim, reducing wrapping a widget in a function like you did cause it forces flutter to rerender the widget rather than using a widget tree to define where the widget needs to be rendered or not.

Answer (score 3):

Bumped into the same issue with a `SlideTransition` taking the full height during a vertical slide. In the end I achieved the slide effect by using a `SizeTransition` instead, and setting its `axisAlignment` property accordingly (-1, 0, 1 for top/center/bottom in my case).